# Scale transition on background image not working correctly in safari when there is a border radius

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions

I have a parent and child div the child div has a background image. On hover the image scales and there is a transition on the transform. This is working correctly in all browsers except Safari, it seems on hover the border radius is being removed and then added again. Can anyone suggest a fix for this.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-box">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-box {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/340x282");
  background-position: center;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
.image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

https://codepen.io/liannaryan/pen/ZxbZZa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue the solution is.

```
.image-box {
   width: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: $border-radius;
   -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, white, white);
 }
```